# Problem saving standard output to variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

Looked some for an answer, but not finding anything that sticks out as a solution.

I'm trying to make a bash script, and in it I need to save the output of `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to a variable. When I run this command in my terminal it spits something to output.

Firstly, why does `myVar=git rev-parse --show-toplevel` not work in my script? The error I'm getting is `rev-parse: command not found`.

Secondly, I think I need to do something like `myVar=${git rev-parse --show-toplevel}`, but this is telling me it's a bad substitution.

Can anyone clarify these things for me, or link to stuff that is relevant? Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need command substitution (`$()`) to save the output of a command in a variable:

```
myVar="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
```

Now to get the value of the variable `myVar`, use `"$myVar"`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Exactly what I needed. Can you tell me about the double-quotes that you're using? I just changed my script, and am not using any quotes anywhere but am getting the correct behavior.

When should I use quotes as you have?

Comment: you can also use backticks myVar= \`git rev-parse --show-toplevel\`

Comment: Also, can you tell me if `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` would return a 0 or 1 (as an exit code) in addition to the text that it outputs? How would I capture the exit code instead of the output text if that were what I was after?

Comment: @noob-in-need check http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/68757 .. the exit status will remain the same to what would be without the variable..